# How to update a paginated jQuery DataTables data and show it

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm having trouble updating the underlying data of the jQuery DataTable. To explain this a little bit, in the case of a non-paginated row I could select the row with jQuery, update it and redraw the changes in DataTables like this `table.row($('#item' + item.id)).invalidate().draw();`

However, when in the case of paginated (non visible) rows, I can not select them with jQuery in order to make an update since DataTables removes them from the DOM and hold them somewhere else. I needed this because an edit in one of my visible rows affects the value in some other row and I want the change to be reflected.

**The following is one of the the attempts I made with no luck:**

I have tried to iterate through the data, update it and redraw the table like this:

```
table.rows().iterator('row', function (context, index) {
    if (this.row(index).data()[0] == item.id /*item is a variable*/) {
        this.row(index).data()[3] = item.qty;
        console.log(this.row(index).data());
        this.row(index).draw();
    }
});
```

The data is logged the way I want it but the change is not shown on the DataTable which led me to think it may not be the correct way to do so.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution without the need to use jQuery:

```
let idData = table.column(0).data();
let idx = idData.indexOf(item.id);

if (idx >= 0) {
    stocksTable.row(idx).data([item.id, item.name, item.desc, item.quantity])).draw(false);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use ajax to modify your back-end data source, then [reload](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()) table data upon modification.

Comment: Your answer works too but I think it's costly to reload the data for the whole table just to update a single value in a row. Besides that, I already have the new data for the row that I want to update. What I want is to update the value for a single paginated row in the table. Thanks for your effort though!

Comment: That approach is dictated by simple logic - as soon as update is made, you must take care to get all the users on the same page.